# $I+A^*A$ is non-singular whenever $A$ is a square matrix with complex entries?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a square matrix with complex entries , then is it true that $I+A^*A$ is non-singular ? where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose

Comment: What does $A^*$ represent?

Comment: @learnmore Adjoint, aka [conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wealll, here's a quick way to see it without introducing the concepts Hermitian, eigen-stuff, or diagonalization.  Look at

$\langle x, (I + A^\ast A)x \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle x, A^\ast A x \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle Ax, Ax \rangle \ge \langle x, x \rangle, \tag{1}$

since $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle \ge 0$.  This shows that for any $x \ne 0$, we have $(I + A^\ast A)x \ne 0$, whence $I + A^\ast A$ must, by definition, be nonsingular.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Very nice! I did not know.

Comment: @Bombyxmori:  and I thank you, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $A^{*}A$ is Hermitian, so it is diagonalizable. Further, all its eigenvalues are non-negative, since $x^{*}A^{*}Ax=\|Ax\|^2\geq0$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $I+A^{*}A$ are all greater than or equal to one. Therefore, non-singular.

Comment: How to show $A^*A$ is hermitian and hence diagonable

Comment: @learnmore, $(A^{*}A)^{*}=A^{*}A$ is the definition of Hermitian and follows from $(AB)^{*}=B^{*}A^{*}$ and $(A^{*})^{*}=A$. It is diagonalizable by the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

Since $A^{*}A$ is Hermitian, under an appropriate change of coordinate we have $A^{*}A\rightarrow D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The same change of coordinates should leave $I$ invariant. So as a linear operator $I+A^{*}A$ is really the same as $I+D$. We know that $D$ is semi-positive-definite because
$$
\langle x, A^{*}Ax\rangle=\langle Ax, Ax\rangle\ge 0
$$
Therefore all of the entries of $D$ are greater or equal to zero. Now it should be clear that $I+A^{*}A$ must be non-singular. In fact a formal inverse can be given by

$$
(I+A^{*}A)^{-1}=I+A^{*}A-(A^{*}A)^{2}\cdots 
$$

Comment: My dear Bombyx, you might want to take a look at your formal series; the signs should alternate, unless I err.  Regards.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Sorry!