# Differential equation for Harmonic Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Particle undergoes simple harmonic motion.

Initially Its displacement is $1$, velocity $1$ and acceleration is $-12$

Compute displacement and acceleration when the velocity is square root of $8$.

I am not familiar with this kind of application question.

So, its displacement is $1$, does that mean that $y=1$ when $x=0$ ?

Comment: @Amzoti:  hi!  good to see you're around.  Can you do me a favor an consider voting to re-open this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997782/iaa-is-non-singular-whenever-a-is-a-square-matrix-with-complex-entries, and then let me know why or why not?  Thanks.

Comment: @Amzoti:  yeah, the nonuniformity bugs me too.  Furthermore, it simply, in the long run, leads people to disrespect/ignore/not take seriously the "policies" they are meant to implement.  One of my thoughts is that the canned reasons provided for closure get hung on questions where they really don't fit.  I would prefer a situation whereby close votes had to be accompanied by a reason stated in the close-voter's own words.

Comment: @Amzoti:  there is a gmail address given on my user page.  If you wpuld be so gracious as to avail yourself of it, perhaps we could have a more extended discussion of such issues?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Amzoti:  yeah, Star Chamber proceedings . . .

Answer (score 2):

Equations for simple harmonic oscillator are 
$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t-\phi),\ v(t)=-A\omega\sin(\omega t-\phi),\ a(t)=-A\omega^2\cos(\omega t-\phi)$$
where $x(t)$ is displacement, $v(t)$ is velocity, $a(t)$ is acceleration.

Initial displacement is 1 means $x(0)=1$.
Plug your initial data to determine $A,\omega,\phi$.

Edit: with initial values $x(0)=1$, $v(0)=1$, $a(0)=-12$ we get:
$a=-\omega^2 x$, i.e. $-12=a(0)=-\omega^2 x(0)$, i.e. $\omega=\pm 2\sqrt{3}$.
$1=x(0)=A\cos\phi$ gives $\cos\phi=1/A$.
$1=x(0)=v(0)=A\cos \phi = A\omega\sin \phi$ gives $\cos\phi=\omega\sin\phi$, i.e.
$\omega=\pm \arctan (1/2\sqrt{3})$, $A=1/\cos\arctan(1/2\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{13/12}$ ($\cos \arctan x = 1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$).
Plugging in $v(0)=1$ you get the value(s) for $\phi=\pm \arcsin (1/\sqrt{13})$.

Then solve the time(s) at which velocity is $\sqrt{8}$ (i.e. $\sqrt{8}=-A\omega \sin(\omega t-\phi)$, where you have the values for $A,\omega,\phi$), and plug such times in the equations for $x$ and $a$.

Comment: I tried to solve it, but couldn't find out value for A and 0

Comment: Edited to include values of $A,\omega$.

Comment: sorry, but I don't still understand how I can find out value for t and displacement and accleration when velocity is square root of 8

Comment: please help me out

Comment: how can I find t ?

Comment: Edited to include how to determine times at which $v(t)=\sqrt{8}$.